# Configuring security in Elasticsearch on docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

How do i enable basic authentication for kibana and elasticsearch on docker container?

I want to have authentication enabled in kibana. With the normal files we can simply set the flag
`xpack.security.enabled=true` and generate the password but since i am running elasticsearch and kibana on docker how do i do it ??
This is my current docker file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.2
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.9.2
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it in env vars while running docker run command for elasticsearch.
Something like this:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "xpack.security.enabled=true" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
```

Comment: This must be run everytime i run docker? right?

Comment: @Tushar you can create a Dockerfile with this cmd

Comment: isnt there any permanent solution?? like we do it locally for a node elastic.yml

Comment: @Tushar yes you can do it using docker compose, set environment variable in docker-compose file. Follow this for more info https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html

Comment: Thanks ! where do i add the run command in my docker file??

Comment: @Tushar Your welcome, feel free to accept if it helps!